# Performance of Javascript Function that makes HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, performance, http, request

I need a way of measuring the response time of a javascript function that creates an http request, that includes the response time of that http request.  I do not have access to modify that funciton however.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var startTime = performance.now(); //log start timestamp
foo.bar(); //The Function that generates an HTTP request
var endTime = performance.now(); //log end timestamp
var diffTime = endTime - startTime;
```

but that only captures the time it takes for the function to generate the request.  Is there a way to capture the response time of the request that gets genearated in javascript?

Comment: Is your http request generated with jQuery ajax or .post/get? If so, call performance.now at the callback.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the function though.  Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Do you get to register any callback to this function?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the timestamp inside of the request callback.

EDIT:

If you want do measure this completely independently from the application (so just by adding another js file), I guess you can decorate XMLHttpRequest.

```
window.XMLHttpRequest = function () {...}
```

Your wrapper will need to have the same API, so that the app still works, and can also measure performance internally.

Comment: Is there a way to extract that via javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. To clarify, you will need to modify the code of the foo.bar function from your example. I assume that you send the request there. The function you attached to get the response will have to include the code for checking the endTime for the request.

Comment: ok thanks, so let me clarify a bit.  I do not have access to modify the foo.bar function, it is not owned by me.  I'm looking for a way to capture the call it takes and find the response time.  Is there a way to capture the response without modifying foo.bar?

Comment: do you have access to the response then? if yes, could you edit your question to include the code you use to access it?

Answer (score 0):

I would usually just hit F12 to bring up dev tools on any browser, go to the network tab, and look at the ajax call that is being made, that will tell you exactly how long the request and repose took with very fine grained details.

However, if you are looking to factor in the java-script that makes the ajax call then start your timer right before the call and stop it on the *complete* event of the ajax call (will require editing the function). that is the only way to catch it if it is asynchronous. And just guessing here based on your description that it is actually an async call, and that explains the behavior of the function just making the ajax call then returning - and not caring about the status or the response...

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using jQuery in your inaccessible function, you can give this a shot:

```
$.when(foo.bar()).done(function()
{
    console.log("Fired after ajax request is done!");
});
```

Take a look also at:

```
var obj = {
  promise: function() {
    // do something
  }
};

$.when( obj ).done( fn );
```

or

```
var obj = {
  promise: foo.bar()
};

$.when( obj ).done( callback );
```

or check out this great article http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

well, if you don't have an acces to the function or you can't edit the ajax call, you can create a listener. the strategy:

1. declare a flag befor the http request call
2. start the call
3. start a listener that loop every X mili-seconds and check for a finish status (outside the ajax function and after it is called)

you should ask yourself: which kind of variables are changed when this call is over? event a visual change on the ui can be used as a flag

and if you wonder how to create your listener.. it looks something like this:

```
function listener()
{
    // do some checks here

    if (done)
    {
         var endTime = performance.now(); //log end timestamp
         var diffTime = endTime - startTime;
    }
    else
    {
         setTimeout(listener(), 100);
    }
}
listener(); // activate the listener
```